# Google Spreadsheet duplication scripts

Tags: duplicates, spreadsheet

I am looking to solve the following situation.

I have a spreadsheet that is my "builder sheet" within a spreadsheet. It has several complex formulas to create resistance training programs for athletes I work with.

I would like to make it so that I "build" the program in that spreadsheetsheet/workbook. Then "on command" duplicate that finished program into a spreadsheet/workbook of my choice. I would need the duplicated copy to be independent and retain all formats and values from the original and does not refer back to the source. This is so that I can change the "builder sheet" to the next program I need to make and repeat without loosing any previous made programs.

As I am a sport performance coach, this would save me a lot of time if this possible.

I understand simply spreadsheet functions but nothing within script languages to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is problem can be solved without any scripting. There are 3 solutions, choose what is better for you:

1. **duplicate an entire spreadsheet with the "builder sheet"**
   [image]
2. **duplicate only the "builder sheet" to the any other spreadsheet on your Google Drive**
   [image]
3. **duplicate only the "builder sheet" in the same spreadsheet**
   [image]